# How to call Webservice from Windows Service?

Tags: .net, web-services, .net-3.5, windows-services, service

How to call Webservice from Windows Service?

I am having one webservice on my Webserver.

I have a windows-service to trigger that webservice.

So I just want to integrate and call my webservice from my windows service.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

`TempWindowService` is name of my windows application

`MyServ` is the name of my reference of my webservice.

```
 TempWindowService.MyServ newService = new TempWindowService.MyServ();
 newService.BatchProcess();
```

Here `BatchProcess()` is the webmethod under my webservice.

**I get error on line**

```
 TempWindowService.MyServ newService = new TempWindowService.MyServ();
```

**Error is as below**

```
 'TempWindowService.MyServ' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'
```

**ANSWER:**

For Those Who are interested in solution to this question, this is the code to be written

```
TempWindowService.MyServ.MyServSoapClient newService = new TempWindowService.MyServ.MyServSoapClient();
```

Hope this Helps everyone looking for a solution to this question. :)

Comment: Eeeeh, I'm a bit confused by your question... Did you try using WCF?

Comment: What is WCF? I am new into this so don't know about WCF?

Comment: Windows Communication Foundation, which plays very well with Web Services.

Comment: @Phillipe: Hey I have added the code above in my question can you please look at it and tell what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd call it just like you would from any application, web or otherwise.  In Visual Studio, [add a Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907578.aspx) for the web service in question to the project for the Windows Service.  This will generate proxy classes for you which you would use in your code to access the web service.

Comment: I would suggest "Add Service Reference" as he is using .NET 3.5 to use WCF

Comment: @David: I am not getting option "Add Web Reference" in my Windows Service. I just get the options "Add Service Reference" and "Add Reference" What should I do in that case?

Comment: @Phillipe: I tried using "Add Service Reference" But then I am not able to declare an object of my webservice so that I can call the webmethods inside my webservice.

Comment: @PARTH: He's right, service reference is likely the way to go in this case.  How are you trying to declare an object of the reference?  Can you edit your question to post the code, as well as what errors you are seeing?

Comment: Yeah sure. Wait a min. I will add it

Comment: @David: I have edited my question. Please check out the code and let me know why it gives this error and what can be done?

Comment: @PARTH: It would appear that `TempWindowService.MyServ` isn't the name of the class, but merely the name of the namespace in which the class resides.  There should also be a class name within that namespace which actually references the service in question.  Note that you're not declaring an instance of the entire web service project, just the individual service (perhaps a .asmx file?) within that project.  That service should have a class name within the given namespace.

Comment: Thanks David. This did help :) Thanks a lot. Actually it should be `TempWindowService.MyServ.MyServSoapClient newService = new TempWindowService.MyServ.MyServSoapClient();`.This worked for me.