# Connect Windows Service to WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2013, windows-services

I'm trying to create a windows service that connects to a WebService from a 3rd party and then parse the reply, repeating every 10 or 15 seconds. I successfully created an example service by following [this MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx) and was perfectly able to install it and run it.

How do I connect to the WebService and how do I get the response?
I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470445/how-to-call-webservice-from-windows-service) and managed to add a web reference and configure the WS, which seems the right way. I also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323898/how-to-connect-to-the-web-service) but it wasn't that enlightning. My problem is what do I do now? The WS has several functions, how do I call the correct one? The functions needs three arguments (username, password and a queue id, all of which I have), how do I add them? Where will the result be stored and how can I access it so I can parse it?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Do you see a "Service References" folder in your windows service project in VS 2013?  Inside that folder you should see an auto-generated class that contains methods for accessing the web service.

Comment: Actually what I managed to add was a Web Reference, not a Service Reference. And there I only have the name I gave to the reference and no methods for it... I'm actually completely lost.. Should it be a Service Reference instead of a Web Reference?

**EDIT:** Actually I should apologize. I wrote service reference instead of web reference in the opening question.. I just corrected it. But the question here remains: should it be service instead of web?

Comment: I suggest you review this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference and determine if you can use a service reference.